# get Combobox binded id in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

hi i have combobox that i bind some feild to it, now i want get item id this is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb" ItemsSource="{Binding School}"  
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Id}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Id}"
                  Width="120"  
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"   
                  Margin="183,39,0,0"   
                                           IsEditable="True"
               IsReadOnly="True"
                                     Text="انتخاب پایه"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="cmb_SelectionChanged_1"  >

                                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SchoolName}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ComboBox>
```

and this is code behind:

```
Console.WriteLine(cmb.SelectedValue);
Console.WriteLine(cmb.SelectedItem);
```

but this is result :

```
{ Id = 1, SchoolName = پيام انقلاب, Base = دوم, Year = 97-98 }
```

i need only id  so where is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually bind to another object of the same type as what's in the collection the combobox is bound to.

For example, say your ItemsSource is a list called Schools.  You create a School property of your class called "SelectedSchool".  Then in your combobox, you create a TwoWay binding to School.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb" ItemsSource="{Binding Schools}"  
    SelectedItem="{Binding Id}" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedSchool, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Width="120"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"   
    Margin="183,39,0,0"   
    IsEditable="True"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    Text="انتخاب پایه"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="cmb_SelectionChanged_1"  >

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SchoolName}"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Then you just get the value from that SelectedSchool property in your codebehind/viewmodel.